# Creating monthly income SUM in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a simple doc on google docs, I have a sheet called "Income"

With A Being name, B being a date, and C being the amount

What I need to do is get the amount for this month, date format is dd/mm/yyyy

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Did my one not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(MONTH(B1:B100)=2,C1:C100,0)))
```

where the B column is dates and C is the amount.

Note that the..
=2
part of the formula is for February.

So,

```
January:  =ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(MONTH(B1:B100)=1,C1:C100,0)))
...
December: =ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(MONTH(B1:B100)=12,C1:C100,0)))
```

Comment: Not quite sure what version of Excel introduced =arrayformula().  if it doesnt work, you can type `=SUM(IF(MONTH(B1:B100)=2,C1:C100,0))` and then `ctrl`+`shft`+`enter`, instead of regular `enter`.

Comment: Thats when I used Yosukesabai's one as =SUM(IF(MONTH(B2:B100)=11,C2:C100,0)) when I tried Seany's it brought back error: Not a number: Date

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius What's in column B?  Are they string?  Or it is understood by Excel that they are date?  If they are string, can I assume that they are zero padded, eg. 16/09/2011 for September 16?

Comment: Ummm its for example 16/11/2011, its just text I think

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius, OK, then you need formla to interpret that text into Excel's date.  hold on.

Comment: @yosukesabai: `ArrayFormula` is used on Google Docs to simulate the Ctrl+Shift+Enter of MS Excel. As OP wanted to make it work on Google Docs, so.

Comment: Yeah, the original question stated Google Docs. If it was in Excel I would have used =SUM(IF(MONTH(B1:B100)=1,C1:C100,0)) and pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. In a Google Spreadsheet we can simply wrap it inside =ArrayFormula(). I have tested my one and it worked fine.

Comment: If your column B is in "text" format you can highlight the column in Google Docs, goto Format -> Number -> Date. This will format your column appropriately. The formula I provided should work then.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sence.  I overlooked Google Doc part

Answer (score 0):

Since the date is not parsed as date but is a string, you should pick up the middle part of string (e.g 11 from 16/11/2011).   If you know that the date is dd/mm/yyyy, zero padded, you can replace `Month(B1:B100)=2` part by `mid(B2:B100,4,2)="02"` (02 for february).

If the numbers are not zero padded (e.g. 16/9/2011 for September 16, as opposed to 16/09/2011), use following for  `Mid()`. 
`MID(B2:B100, FIND("/",B2:B100)+1, FIND("/",MID(B2:B100,FIND("/",B2:B100)+1,9999))-1)`

here, the second chunk `FIND("/",B2:B100)+1` find the first occurence of "/", then move one char to right (+1).  Then the last chunk `FIND("/",MID(B2:B100,FIND("/",B2:B100)+1,9999))-1)` looks for next "/" from the string that has throw away date part.  and in this case compare against "2" for feburary, not "02".

And this array formula deal is two confusing, you can just add one column which specifies month of the transaction.  The formla should be`=MID(B2, FIND("/",B2)+1, FIND("/",MID(B2,FIND("/",B2)+1,9999))-1)`.  Have this formula in column D, for example, and paste down.  if you want numeric values instead, you can use `=VALUE(MID(B2, FIND("/",B2)+1, FIND("/",MID(B2,FIND("/",B2)+1,9999))-1))` and now you can compare against 2, instead of "2" or "02".